# Reasons why a sentient universe would create life?

Tags: science-fiction, universe, life

The basic idea I had was that the universe basically thought itself into being and from there decided to create life. It sent out the seeds for life to begin, then created a race to watch over things. Although I've not quite had the inspiration on why it created life in the first place. What are some interesting reasons as to why it did beyond "it was lonely" ?

Comment: First it's opinion based. Second it's really against most established philosophy and logic. It's not the place to discuss the matter. Suffice to say: A can NOT just think itself to being. That carries an obvious contradiction if you think about it. Also it's not even related to world building. Please check like the help center https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: The Hindu religion would be an excellent place to start
  Brahman has some of the attributes you are seeking.

Comment: It's an [ineffable mystery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ineffability). Also see: Good Omens.

Comment: inevitability. an _infinite_ universe will, eventually, do _everything_. and universes tend to be infinite.

Comment: Either the universe existed forever, or it came into existance at one time. If the universe came into existence it either did so by chance events or because some preexisting intelligence created it for some reason.  And possbily a hyopthetical intelligent universe might create life within it for the same reasons a hypothetical preexisting intelligence might create a universe.

Answer (score 2):

**Randomness**

[image]

The universe is a giant brain but everything is cause and effect. Life add some randomness to the equation a bit like the butterfly in China causing hurricanes in the Pacific.

Answer (score 2):

Pure amusement, you never know *what* those fleshy things will get up to next. You can watch them for billions, even billions of years, and they will always find some new way to surprise.